# Installation of Opensis with XAMPP 7.2.13-0 on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: server, apache2, xampp

I am trying to install Opensis-ce 6.0 on Ubuntu 18.04.
I followed the the procedure given by [CAMAPP](https://camapp.wordpress.com/2016/02/18/installing-opensis-on-ubuntu/)

**Correction since initial post**

Steps 1 to 11 were executed successfully
However when i executed step 12 i got the following message after executing the command given

Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

I could not include the logs from: "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" because they contained more than 8 links

Before executing step 12, I verified the following
MySQL Database     Running 
ProFTPD            Running 
Apache Web Server  Running

I also verified that Xampp was setup correctly. by typing  in the address bar. when i did that and pressed enter, The Xampp home page came up. i used Opera browser

[Xampps WElcome Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8YIv.png)

I also verified phpMyAdmin was installed correctly by typing
http://localhost/phpmyadmin in the address bar and pressing enter
when i did the expected page appeared

[phpmyadmin opening page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nv4s8.png)

i made a further observation.
Using the Xampp 7.2.13-0 Graphical server manager tool. When i click on "go to applications" i get the following error message in the terminal window:

xdg-open: no method available for opening 'http://localhost:80'

I would like to know what to do to complete the installation of Opensis-ce
Thanks much

Note: i also tried using localhost port 81 and 82 instead of port 80 as some suggested without success

Comment: I attempted to include the logs from "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" was prevented from doing so by "askubuntu"  the reason given was that "i needed to have 10 reputations to include more than 8 links"

Comment: i am new to linux / ubuntu;  just about 5 months